# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, kapt

I get this error when I build my project. Could you please help me? What can be a problem?
I Googled some options but it seems that nothing helped.
I suppose there might be some problem with Hilt dependency but I'm not sure.
Thank you.
..........................................................................

[image]

This is my app Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.mycurencyconverter'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mycurencyconverter"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02"


    // Activity KTX for viewModels()
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1"

    // Architectural Components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"

    // Lifecycle
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"
}
```

Top-level Gradle:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and change it?

**gradle(:app)**

```
  //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02"
```

**gradle(project)**

```
 // You can add it just below the ids.
 id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
```